# Any relation between $A^T P A$ and $A P A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

For some positive-definite symmetric matrix P, are there any known relationships between $A^T P A$ and $A P A^T$? (where $A$ may be non-invertible in general)

Update:
Using the [Matrix Inversion Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), I was able to show that $PA(P^{-1} + A^T P A)^{-1} = (P^{-1} + A P A^T)^{-1}AP$, but this is a bit more complicated than I was hoping. Still looking for other relationships and insights! Specifically, I am hoping for an explicit equation for $A^T P A$ in terms of $A P A^T$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $P$ is the identity matrix, do you expect an explicit equation for $A^TA$ in terms of $AA^T$? Try picking some $A$, doing both calculations, and see whether there's any relation.

Answer (score 1):

For example if $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then $A=A^T$, hence $A^TPA = APA^T$. I think it depends what type of matrix $A$ is.

Comment: If you write $A$ as the sum $A=A_S+A_A$ of its symetric ($A_S$) and antisymetric ($A_A$) components, then you get that $A^TPA=APA^T$ iff $A_SPA_A=A_APA_S$. This includes the cases $A_A=0$ (symetric) and $A_S=0$ (antisymetric).

Comment: Should have left that comment as an answer, thanks!